# Placing header on top, but not over content. Making the content to be below the header

Tags: html, css, angular, header

I have a problem with CSS where I am not able to making the header to be on top and like fixed, not over the content.

I want the content to be under the header like two separated divs.

html:

```html
<body>
  <mat-toolbar style=" position: fixed;background-color: black; color: white">
    <button mat-raised-button
      routerLink="/profile"
      class="buttons"> About me</button>
    <h1 style="margin: auto;">LoL Not Alone</h1>
    <button mat-raised-button> Donate </button>
  </mat-toolbar>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</body>
```

css:

```css
button{
  background-color: #61c4d1;
  color: black;
}

mat-button-toggle{
  background-color: #61c4d1;
  color: black;
}


mat-toolbar{
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

What can I add for the content (`router-outlet`) to be below the header and the header to be like fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: It should have the text under the header which is a menu fixed on top. Hope that helps!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

button{
  background-color: #61c4d1;
  color: black;
}

mat-button-toggle{
  background-color: #61c4d1;
  color: black;
}


mat-toolbar{
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

body {margin:0;}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.main {
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 1500px; /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="/profile">About me</a>
  <a href="/profile">Donate</a>
  <a href="/profile">Donate</a>
</div>


<div class="main">

 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   
    <h1 style="margin: auto;">LoL Not Alone</h1>
 
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Which part of the code keeps it fixed? Thanks.